Self-reference entities SaveChanges failure!! Am I missing something?
I have an entity
public class ExpenseCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public ExpenseCategory? Parent { get; set; }

    public int? PreviousSiblingId { get; set; }
    public ExpenseCategory? PreviousSibling { get; set; }

    public int? NextSiblingId { get; set; }
    public ExpenseCategory? NextSibling { get; set; }


    public List<ExpenseCategory> Children { get; set; } = [];

    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; } = [];
}


in my DbContext I have
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseCategory>().ToTable("ExpenseCategory")
          .HasOne(e => e.Parent)
          .WithMany(e => e.Children)
          .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // Prevents cascading deletes

        // Configuring the ExpenseCategory entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseCategory>()
            .HasKey(ec => ec.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseCategory>()
            .Property(ec => ec.Label)
            .IsRequired(); // Ensure Label is required

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseCategory>()
            .HasOne(e => e.PreviousSibling)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<ExpenseCategory>(e => e.PreviousSiblingId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseCategory>()
            .HasOne(e => e.NextSibling)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<ExpenseCategory>(e => e.NextSiblingId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);



in the forms code i have a
    private void AddRootButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var label = GetNewCategoryLabel();
        if (label.IsNullOrEmpty()) return;

        ExpenseCategory? prevCategory = null;

        TreeNode? prevNode = null;
        var rootNodes = TV.Nodes;
        if (rootNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            prevNode = rootNodes[rootNodes.Count - 1];
            if (prevNode != null)
            {
                prevCategory = (ExpenseCategory)prevNode.Tag;
            }
        }

        // Create new category
        var newCategory = new ExpenseCategory()
        {
            Label = label,
            Parent = null,
            PreviousSibling = prevCategory,
            NextSibling = null, // Initially null
            Children = [],
            Expenses = []
        };

        // Add new category to the context
        var entry = _context.ExpenseCategories.Add(newCategory);

        // Setup sibling references conditionally
        if (prevCategory != null)
        {
            // Set the NextSibling of the previous category to the new one
            prevCategory.NextSibling = entry.Entity;
            entry.Entity.PreviousSibling = prevCategory; // Establish mutual reference
        }
        else
        {
            // If there's no previous category, we can explicitly set null to avoid confusion
            entry.Entity.PreviousSibling = null;
        }

        // Add the new node to the TreeView
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(newCategory.Label)
        {
            Tag = newCategory
        };

        var index = TV.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        TV.SelectedNode = TV.Nodes[index];
        ActiveControl = TV;

        // Note: _context.SaveChanges() will be called later
    }


As I want _cοntext to SaveChanges when the form closing and not when a new entry is entered
I am calling this
   private async void ExpenseCategoriesDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        await SaveChangesWithTrackingChecksAsync();
    }


   private async Task SaveChangesWithTrackingChecksAsync()
   {
       try
       {
           foreach (var entry in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ExpenseCategory>())
           {
               var category = entry.Entity;
               Debug.WriteLine($"Entity: {category.Label}, State: {entry.State}");

               // Check PreviousSibling and NextSibling presence and tracking status
               if (category.PreviousSibling != null)
               {
                   var previousSiblingEntry = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Entity == category.PreviousSibling);
                   if (previousSiblingEntry == null)
                   {
                       Debug.WriteLine($"    PreviousSibling (Label: {category.PreviousSibling.Label}, Id: {category.PreviousSibling.Id}) is NOT being tracked. Attaching it now.");
                       _context.Attach(category.PreviousSibling);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Debug.WriteLine($"    PreviousSibling (Label: {category.PreviousSibling.Label}, Id: {category.PreviousSibling.Id}) is being tracked.");
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine("    PreviousSibling is null.");
               }

               if (category.NextSibling != null)
               {
                   var nextSiblingEntry = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Entity == category.NextSibling);
                   if (nextSiblingEntry == null)
                   {
                       Debug.WriteLine($"    NextSibling (Label: {category.NextSibling.Label}, Id: {category.NextSibling.Id}) is NOT being tracked. Attaching it now.");
                       _context.Attach(category.NextSibling);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Debug.WriteLine($"    NextSibling (Label: {category.NextSibling.Label}, Id: {category.NextSibling.Id}) is being tracked.");
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine("    NextSibling is null.");
               }

               // Additional check to verify sibling chain integrity
               if (category.NextSibling?.PreviousSibling != category)
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine($"Warning: {category.Label}'s NextSibling ({category.NextSibling?.Label}) does not reference {category.Label} as PreviousSibling.");
               }

               if (category.PreviousSibling?.NextSibling != category)
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine($"Warning: {category.Label}'s PreviousSibling ({category.PreviousSibling?.Label}) does not reference {category.Label} as NextSibling.");
               }
           }

           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
       }
       catch (NullReferenceException ex)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("NullReferenceException encountered: " + ex.Message);
           throw;
       }
   }

When I add 1 and 2 as input entries when SaveChangesAsync is hit i get
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

while on the Output window i get
Entity: 1, State: Added
    PreviousSibling is null.
    NextSibling (Label: 2, Id: 0) is being tracked.
Warning: 1's PreviousSibling () does not reference 1 as NextSibling.
Entity: 2, State: Added
    PreviousSibling (Label: 1, Id: 0) is being tracked.
    NextSibling is null.
Warning: 2's NextSibling () does not reference 2 as PreviousSibling.
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.



As you can see although the references are correctly assigned I keep getting this exception and i can not figure out if this is an EFCore wickness or I am missing something!!!
Also the
Warning: 1's PreviousSibling () does not reference 1 as NextSibling.

and the
Warning: 2's NextSibling () does not reference 2 as PreviousSibling.

are not valid as 1's PreviousSibling is null so there is no NextSibling for 1's PreviousSibling
and also the 2's NextSibling is also null so there is no PreviousSibling for 2's NextSibling as well
Entries are saved correctly if i call SaveChanges after each entry input!!
Can you help please as I have spent hours trying to figure out why EFCore fails to save such a simple relationhsip's data!!
Thanx in advance
I have shown you above what i have tried so far
Only when savechanges is called immediately after the new entry is added works well
Otherwise when the form closes I always get an exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object and i can not figure out which object reference is not set to an instance of an object

That is a whole lot of work to try and manage tracked and untracked entities which may be hiding problems. What you are may be missing is handling the situations where another reference to a specific entity happens to be tracked.  A check against the tracking cache might not find the specific instance you are looking for, but it should handle if it finds a different instance with the same ID before attempting an Attach. That wouldn't result in a NullRef, but a different exception.
There are a couple other issues I see. First, structure your collections to protect the setters. When working with entities you never want to have a situation where collections are re-initialized. EF works by tracking references so no code should ever re-initialize them otherwise you completely break change tracking.
public List<ExpenseCategory> Children { get; } = [];

public List<Expense> Expenses { get; } = [];

Wherever this breaks in your code is a problem area.
Next, I would honestly remove the PreviousSibling/NextSibling FKs/relationships entirely. This is a denormalization of the relational structure between parents and children. While it seems useful to have a convenient double-linked-list relationship, the problem with introducing something like this in the relational model is that it is impractical to impossible to enforce. The basic rule is that a "sibling" should always be another child of the same parent, but there is no way to enforce that. A previous/next sibling ID could be set to any ExpenseId.
If you want the convenience of a double-linked-list in your structure I would recommend using an unmapped one. ExpenseCategory would need a SortOrder so that a parent with children would arrange the "siblings" in a predictable ranked order then an ExpenseCategory could find their siblings from within the parent:
[NotMapped]
public ExpenseCategory? PreviousSibling => Parent.Children.Where(c => c.SortOrder < SortOrder).OrderByDescending(c => c.SortOrder).FirstOrDefault();

[NotMapped]
public ExpenseCategory? NextSibling => Parent.Children.Where(c => c.SortOrder > SortOrder).OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).FirstOrDefault();

This would mean that you cannot use Previous/Next Sibling in a query expression, and to work when viewing/editing an expense at a given level you want to ensure that it's Parent and Parent.Children are eager-loaded.
Moving siblings around would involve exchanging SortOrder values. Inserting would involve incrementing all SortOrders after the insertion point. Likewise deleting a sibling should decrement sort orders after the deletion point to close gaps.  Simplifying that relationship to work through Parent.Children will probably remove whatever issue is getting tripped up by the logic trying to juggle the double-linked-list relationships alongside the parent-children one.
